# Which php framework has module/bundle/whatever-reusable-package extending as default?

Tags: php, codeigniter, zend-framework, cakephp, laravel

Right now I find out that extending modules in CodeIgniter framework using MX HMVC is very bad and not supported by default and I have a custom function in MY_Controller and you need to make a "hack"..the main point is it doesn't work good.

My question is if CodeIgniter didn't offer extending modules with other modules e.g. Drupal way of modules. Where e.g. you have core Views module and than module for extending Views so you can have Slideshow as a view and then another that add something else to the slideshow and every module use something from previous module in hierarchy like:

Views -> Views Slideshow -> Views Slideshow Extended

Which PHP frameworks has this "extending" ability in modular way. **I am not looking for extensions of classic MVC controllers/models like:**

```
class Views Slideshow extends Views {...
```

**I need a PHP framework that have in mind extending of modules/bundles/whatever-packages**

I have a hard time with CodeIgniter so I am looking for some other framework that is capable of this within a core. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Symfony2 definitely have this in mind, as everything is a `Bundle`. Even the framework is a `Bundle`.

You can pretty much overload almost everything in Symfony2, given that you use the service container instead of hard dependencies. Be careful that this might introduce some complexity (the price of the overloading feature). Also you can reduce complexity (and learning curve), as using the service container is not mandatory.

Please take a look at the documentation of Symfony2: [Architecture](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/quick_tour/the_architecture.html), and more specifically the [Understanding the bundle system](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/quick_tour/the_architecture.html#understanding-the-bundle-system)